# Merge separate divergent size and fill (or color) legends in ggplot showing absolute magnitude with the size scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am plotting some multivariate data where I have 3 discrete variables and one continuous.
I want the size of each point to represent the magnitude of change rather than the actual numeric value. I figured that I can achieve that by using absolute values. With that in mind I would like to have negative values colored blue, positive red and zero with white. Than to make a plot where the legend would look like this:

[image: example.png]

I came up with dummy dataset which has the same structure as my dataset, to get a reproducible example:

```
a1 <- c(-2, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, -0.5)
a2 <- c(-2, -2, -1.5, 2, 1, 0)
a3 <- c(1.5, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 0)
a4 <- c(2, 0.5, 0, 1, -1.5, 0.5)
cond1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
cond2 <- c("L", "L", "H", "H", "S", "S")
df <- data.frame(cond1, cond2, a1, a2, a3, a4)

#some data munging
df <- df %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "animal",
                          values_to = "FC",
                          cols = c(a1:a4)) %>%
  mutate(across(c("cond1", "cond2", "animal"),
                as.factor)) %>% 
  mutate(fillCol = case_when(FC < 0 ~ "decrease",
                             FC > 0 ~ "increase",
                             FC == 0 ~ "no_change"))

# plot 1
plt1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cond2, y = animal)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = abs(FC), color = FC)) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low='blue',
                        mid='white',
                        high='red',
                        limits=c(-2,2),
                        breaks=c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2))+
  facet_wrap(~cond1)
plt1

#plot 2
plt2 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cond2, y = animal)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = abs(FC), color = factor(FC))) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)
plt2

#plot 3
cols <- c("decrease" = "blue", "no_change" = "white", "increase" = "red")
plt3 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cond2, y = animal)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = abs(FC), color = fillCol)) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "FC",
                     values = cols,
                     labels = c("< 0", "0", "> 0"),
                     guide = "legend") +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)
plt3
```

So the result should be looking basically like plt3 but the legend should be something looking like merging those two legends in plt2. The smallest point would be zero in the middle and increasingly bigger points to negative and positive direction, with colors red = positive, blue = negative, white = zero and the labels on the legends showing the actual numbers. I was tasked with this, but I can not figure it out.
This is my first question on Stackoverflow so no images :( . I am relatively new to r.

Thank you!

Edit 12/08/2021
Per @jared_mamrot kind reply below, it only works if the values in the FC variable are somehow regular. But when I change some numbers it shows as a warning and won't show the point on plot. Is it possible to define manual scale with ranges of values or bin it somehow?
Example with changed values:

```
a1 <- c(-2, 2, 1.4, 0, 0.8, -0.5)
a2 <- c(-2, -2, -1.5, 2, 1, 0)
a3 <- c(1.8, 2, 1, 2, 0.6, 0.4)
a4 <- c(2, 0.2, 0, 1, -1.2, 0.5)
cond1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
cond2 <- c("L", "L", "H", "H", "S", "S")
df <- data.frame(cond1, cond2, a1, a2, a3, a4)

df <- df %>% pivot_longer(names_to = "animal",
                          values_to = "FC",
                          cols = c(a1:a4)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                as.factor))
 
plt4 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cond2, y = animal, color = FC, size = FC)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(10,8,6,4,3,4,6,8,10),
                    breaks = seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                    limits = factor(seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                                    levels = seq(-2, 2, 0.5))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("-2" = "#03254C",
                                "-1.5" = "#1167B1",
                                "-1" = "#187BCD",
                                "-0.5" = "#2A9DF4",
                                "0" = "white",
                                "0.5" = "#FAD65F",
                                "1" = "#F88E2A",
                                "1.5" = "#FC6400",
                                "2" = "#B72C0A"),
                     breaks = seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                     limits = factor(seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                                     levels = seq(-2, 2, 0.5))) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)

plt4
```

```
> Warning message:
> Removed 7 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you want to map absolute values to size, and true values to color (divergent scale). I think binning the data is a great idea, but it wasn't mine, so I won't pursue this path (I encourage user Skaqqs to try an answer based on their suggestion).

I personally would prefer to keep your size as a continuous variable, thus you'd still be able to use `scale_size_continuous`. This requires:

- separate the data into negative, positive, and "zero" values and use separate scales for your fill or color aesthetic (easy with {ggnewscale})
- use absolute values for the size aesthetic

Trying to do fancy things with guides can very quickly become quite hacky. Instead of doing crazy stuff with guide functions etc, I really prefer to separate legend creation into a new plot, ("fake legend") and add the legend to the other plot (e.g., with {patchwork}).

The look / relative dimensions can obviously be changed according to your aesthetic desires, and I think easier so than when dealing with real guides.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(patchwork)

a1 <- c(-2, 2, 1.4, 0, 0.8, -0.5)
a2 <- c(-2, -2, -1.5, 2, 1, 0)
a3 <- c(1.8, 2, 1, 2, 0.6, 0.4)
a4 <- c(2, 0.2, 0, 1, -1.2, 0.5)
cond1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
cond2 <- c("L", "L", "H", "H", "S", "S")
df <- data.frame(cond1, cond2, a1, a2, a3, a4)

df <- 
  df %>% pivot_longer(names_to = "animal", values_to = "FC", cols = c(a1:a4)) %>%
  ## keep your continuous variable continuous:
  ## make a new column which tells you what is negative and positve and zero
  ## turn FC into absolute values 
  mutate(across(-FC, as.factor), 
         signFC = ifelse(FC == 0, 0, sign(FC)), 
         FC = abs(FC)) 

## move data and certain aesthetics from main call to layers
## I am also using fillable points, in order to be able to show "zero" in white
p <- ggplot(mapping = aes(x = cond2, y = animal, size = FC)) +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, signFC == -1), aes(fill = FC), shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_fermenter(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
  ## to show negative and positives differently, but size information still 
  ## mapped to continuous scale
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()+
  geom_point(data = filter(df, signFC == 1), aes(fill = FC), shape = 21, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_fermenter(palette = "Reds", direction = 1) +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, signFC == 0), fill = "white", shape = 21) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, 2)) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1) +
  theme(legend.position = "none")

## When dealing with guides gets too messy, I prefer to cleanly build the legend
## as a different plot
leg_df <- 
  data.frame(breaks = seq(-2, 2, 0.5)) %>%
  mutate(br_sign = ifelse(breaks == 0, 0, sign(breaks)), 
         vals = abs(breaks), 
         y = seq_along(vals)) 

## Do all the above, again :)
p_leg <-
  ggplot(mapping = aes(x = 1, y = y, size = vals)) +
  geom_text(data = leg_df, aes(x = 1, label = breaks, y = y), inherit.aes = FALSE,
            nudge_x = .01, hjust = 0) +
  geom_point(data = filter(leg_df, br_sign == -1), aes(fill = vals), shape = 21) +
  scale_fill_fermenter(palette = "Blues", direction = 1) +
  ## to show negative and positives differently, but size information still 
  ## mapped to continuous scale
  ggnewscale::new_scale_fill()+
  geom_point(data = filter(leg_df, br_sign == 1), aes(fill = vals), shape = 21, show.legend = FALSE) +
  scale_fill_fermenter(palette = "Reds", direction = 1) +
  geom_point(data = filter(leg_df, br_sign == 0), fill = "white", shape = 21) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(0, 2)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = "none",
        plot.margin = margin(l = 10, r = 15, unit = "pt")) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")

p + p_leg + plot_layout(widths = c(1, .05))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks! This looks promising, I will give it a shot with my data later today. One question, is there a way to make the points appear bigger in general? Like the size of each point would be twice the size, jus for the looks?

Comment: Solved by adding `range`

Comment: Your solution was the most useful one and I achieved my goal using it with some additional changes. I didn't want gradient fill, so I specified for positive values red color and blue for negatives, the same as you showed for "0". Also, took me a while to figure out to add legend label, solved by adding title to the second "legend" plot and adjusting it's position. All other answers were very useful to learn new things! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 6):

One potential solution is to specify the values manually for each scale, e.g.

```r
library(tidyverse)
a1 <- c(-2, 2, 1, 0, 0.5, -0.5)
a2 <- c(-2, -2, -1.5, 2, 1, 0)
a3 <- c(1.5, 2, 1, 2, 0.5, 0)
a4 <- c(2, 0.5, 0, 1, -1.5, 0.5)
cond1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
cond2 <- c("L", "L", "H", "H", "S", "S")
df <- data.frame(cond1, cond2, a1, a2, a3, a4)

#some data munging
df %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "animal",
               values_to = "FC",
               cols = c(a1:a4)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                as.factor)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = cond2, y = animal, color = FC, size = FC)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size_manual(values = c(10,8,6,4,3,4,6,8,10),
                    breaks = seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                    limits = factor(seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                                    levels = seq(-2, 2, 0.5))) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("-2" = "#03254C",
                                "-1.5" = "#1167B1",
                                "-1" = "#187BCD",
                                "-0.5" = "#2A9DF4",
                                "0" = "white",
                                "0.5" = "#FAD65F",
                                "1" = "#F88E2A",
                                "1.5" = "#FC6400",
                                "2" = "#B72C0A"),
                     breaks = seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                     limits = factor(seq(-2, 2, 0.5),
                                     levels = seq(-2, 2, 0.5))) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-12-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Hi, this was helpful, but it seems like it works only in the example data, when I factor my actual data it gives ~64 levels for the FC variable, the values are Log10 fold changes which are not regularly spaced At least I think when I tried to run it it just removes all the values: `Warning message:
Removed 70 rows containing missing values (geom_point). ` Is it because the manually set values have to match the values in that variable? Is it possible to define the manual scale with ranges? Thank you!

Comment: I tried to change some numbers in the input df, and if you change anything to some different decimal, like 1 to 1.2. That value will be in the warning as missing value and wouldn't show in the plot

Comment: Yep - I see the problem - I thought it was weird that your fold changes were 'binned'.  Is there any reason why you can't upload your actual data? It would make it a lot easier to work on potential solutions

Comment: Unfortunately, I can not upload the actual data as those are yet to be published. I edited my question and in second part included example with slightly changed values. The structure of the input is the same, just the values for FC are numeric in interval (-4,4), I tried to use `cut` function to get continuous data to discrete bins to use manual scale, but I cannot figure out how to assign special bin just for zero value

Comment: I've spent some time testing out different approaches but I haven't been able to get your desired outcome sorry. I'll place a bounty on your question tomorrow and see if anyone else has a better solution.

Comment: Thanks! I spent hours to solve it, but I am still a newbie in R. I am still working on it but running out of ideas.

Comment: @jared_mamrot @jaro_sk how about binning the data before plotting? What are your criteria for binning? If you want to round up to the nearest 0.5, you could use this `df$FC_bin <- a.factor(plyr::round_any(as.numeric(paste(df$FC)), 0.5))`. Then update your aes from `FC` to `FC_bin`.

Comment: @Skaqqs I thought about binning, but I would end up with too many bins in some cases, I have multiple datasets with the same structure, and some have only subtle differences. I will give it a shot and check how it looks. The bins have to be smaller, but the goal is to have the size of the points/circles as continuous variable. In the case of binning, it should be possible to define smaller bins, like 0.25 (or even smaller) and define legend manually to show only 0.5 steps, right?

Comment: Jared, to put my two cents worth - although the OP has accepted my answer (it seems to be more handy for their use case), I believe that user @Skaqqs 's answer is way simpler and in my opinion deserves the bounty. (I still don't understand why this solution would work, but it does!)

Comment: Thanks @tjebo, I also like your approach, but I agree that Skaqqs answer is clear/clever and deserves the bounty (love learning new things). Thanks for being such an outstanding contributor to SO. Also, based on OP's variable names they're working with RNA-Seq data, so I suspect facetted smear and volcano plots would be the 'best' solution ([XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)) so overall I think it's great that the bounty led to two excellent answers.

Answer (score 6):

My understanding is that ggplot will automatically combine scales in the legend if the scales are defined by the same variable (`FC_num`), breaks, and labels. This means we don't have to use `scale...manual()`, which should make our code a lot more flexible and concise(!).

Here are two options:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

a1 <- c(-2, 2, 1.4, 0, 0.8, -0.5)
a2 <- c(-2, -2, -1.5, 2, 1, 0)
a3 <- c(1.8, 2, 1, 2, 0.6, 0.4)
a4 <- c(2, 0.2, 0, 1, -1.2, 0.5)
cond1 <- c("A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B")
cond2 <- c("L", "L", "H", "H", "S", "S")
dff <- data.frame(cond1, cond2, a1, a2, a3, a4)

#some data munging
df <- dff %>%
  pivot_longer(names_to = "animal",
               values_to = "FC",
               cols = c(a1:a4)) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                as.factor))

# Make focal variable numeric
df$FC_num <- as.numeric(paste(df$FC))

# Define breaks based on focal variable
breaks <- seq(min(df$FC_num), max(df$FC_num), 0.5)

# Option 1
transAbs <- scales::trans_new(name="abs", transform=abs, inverse=abs)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=cond2, y=animal, fill=FC_num, size=FC_num)) +
  geom_point(pch=21) +
  scale_size_continuous(range=c(3,10), trans=transAbs, breaks=breaks, labels=breaks) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="RdBu", breaks=breaks, labels=breaks) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE), size=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)

# Option 2
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=cond2, y=animal, fill=FC_num, size=FC_num)) +
  geom_point(pch=21) +
  scale_size_binned_area(max_size=10, breaks=breaks, labels=breaks) +
  scale_fill_distiller(palette="RdBu", breaks=breaks, labels=breaks) +
  guides(fill=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE), size=guide_legend(reverse=TRUE)) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)
```

[image]

Comment: didn't know that behaviour of scale_size_area. very interesting! Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Based on OP's requirement to represent data with point sizes corresponding to the magnitude of change and colors indicating the direction (positive, negative, or zero), I made two additions to OP's `plt1` plot:

1. Added `scale_size_continuous` with the same limits as `scale_color_gradient2`. This ensures that the point sizes are in sync with the value magnitudes.
2. Added `guides` with `guide_legend` to merge the legends for color and size. The key part is `override.aes` within the size guide, with a vector of divergent size values (`c(5, 3, 1, 3, 5)`).

The legend shows how the point sizes vary with the `FC` value, alongside the color indications for positive, negative, and zero values.

I'm using the same dummy dataset provided. Here's the modified `plt1` code:

```
plt1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = cond2, y = animal)) +
  geom_point(aes(size = abs(FC), color = FC)) +
  scale_color_gradient2(low = 'blue', mid = 'white', high = 'red',
                        limits = c(-2, 2), breaks = c(-2, -1, 0, 1, 2)) +
  scale_size_continuous(limits = c(-2, 2)) +
  guides(color = guide_legend(title = "FC", reverse = TRUE),
         size = guide_legend(title = "FC", reverse = TRUE,
                             override.aes = list(size = c(5, 3, 1, 3, 5)))) +
  facet_wrap(~cond1)

plt1
```

[image: Plot depicting change magnitude with point size and direction with color]